# How do I use NMinimize to solve equations obtained using NIntegrate?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I wish to minimize following equation with respect to variables $h,p,q,t$:

$\qquad f(h,p,q,t)=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{dx\,dy}{\sqrt{h^2+x^2+y^2-2\,x\,y\space cos(p)+2\,h\,y\,cos(q)-2\,h\,x\,cos(t)}}$.

If I try to integrate this double integral using Mathematica it reduces it to a single integral:

$\qquad f(h,p,q,t)=- \int_o^1 \ln\big[-x \, cos(p)+h \, cos(q)+ \sqrt{h^2 +x^2-2\,h\,x \,cos(t)}\,\big] dx \\ \qquad + \int_0^1 \ln  \big [1-x\, cos(p)+h\,cos(q)+ \sqrt{1+h^2+x^2-2\,x\,cos(q) - 2\,h\,x\,cos(t)} \big] dx $

Any further operation using `Integrate` does not work. So, I tried to use `NIntegrate` instead. `NIntegrate` doesn't work if you have have variables in the integrand that are not a variable of integration. So, the way out is this:

I created the integral as a function of the variables that don't participate in the integral.

```
 FUNC[p_, q_, h_, t_] := 
   NIntegrate[Log[-x Cos[p] + h Cos[q] + Sqrt[h^2 + x^2 - 2 h x Cos[t]]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Now `FUNC[Pi/3, Pi/2, 6, Pi/6]` gives me 1.66971, which is great. But I really need the integral to run a minimization on the variables `h,p,q`, and `t`.

So, I tried this next:

```
NMinimize[
  {FUNC[p, q, h, t], {-Pi <= p <= Pi, -Pi <= q <= Pi, h >= 0, -Pi <= t <= Pi}}, 
  {p, q, h, t}]
```

And I get errors.

Is my entire approach wrong? Or it is partially wrong? Any feedback is most welcome.

#### Solution

```
FUNC[(p_)?NumericQ, (q_)?NumericQ, (h_)?NumericQ, (t_)?NumericQ] := 
   NIntegrate[
    If[(-x)*Cos[p] + h*Cos[q] + Sqrt[h^2 + x^2 - 2*h*x*Cos[t]] > 0, 
      Log[(-x)*Cos[p] + h*Cos[q] + Sqrt[h^2 + x^2 - 2*h*x*Cos[t]]]], 
    {x, 0, 1}];
NMinimize[
  {Re[FUNC[p, q, h, t]], {-Pi <= p <= Pi, -Pi <= q <= Pi, h >= 0, -Pi <= t <= Pi}}, 
  {p, q, h, t}]
```

Mathematica result:

> ```
> {-10.5339, {p -> -0.0248342, q -> 2.54783, h -> 0.0265091, t -> -2.523}}
> ```

This `NMinimize` makes sense to me. I'm minimizing energy here and I didn't incorporated an negative sign and this the minimized result is negative.

Comment: how about this? `ClearAll[FUNC]; 
FUNC[(p_)?NumericQ, (q_)?NumericQ, 
    (h_)?NumericQ, 
    (t_)?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
    If[(-x)*Cos[p] + h*Cos[q] + 
       Sqrt[h^2 + x^2 - 2*h*x*
          Cos[t]] > 0, 
     Log[(-x)*Cos[p] + h*Cos[q] + 
       Sqrt[h^2 + x^2 - 2*h*x*
          Cos[t]]]], {x, 0, 1}]; 
NMinimize[{FUNC[p, q, h, t], 
   {-Pi <= p <= Pi, -Pi <= q <= Pi, 
    h >= 0, -Pi <= t <= Pi}}, 
  {p, q, h, t}]`　Type Checking and Singularity Elimination.

Comment: 1)Perhaps there is a typo in the original expression $f[h,p,q,t]$, check $-hc\cos {(t)}$  it should be   $-hx\cos {(t)}$; 2)the integral is expressed as a `ConditionalExpression` with many constraints; 3)To avoid mistakes we need to minimize Re[FUNC].  Is it possible to immediately put a restriction on $f(h,p,q,t)$, so that `Im[f]=0`?

Comment: Xminer: Thanks for the ?Numeric and IF statement trick. This got some of the errors fixed. Alex: Thanks for catching the typo. I'll fix it. Also, thanks for the suggestion for minimizing real valued portion of the function. It works well now. Thanks to both of you for your help. :)

Comment: Further discussion: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037